# Flutter app crashes after button click navigating to SecondRoute

Tags: flutter, dart, here-api

I have implemented the HERE map SDK into an existing app, with it fully functioning when I run the singular page within the project file on an emulator.

However, when I begin the emulator on my home page and navigate to the map via a button, it begins to load and then crashes within 5 seconds.

I am sure it is an issue with the setup of the map.dart SecondRoute page, but cannot figure out where the adaptation is required.

Here is the map code we are using, the button is just a simple elevated button. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Button-

```
onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
                );
                },
                ),
```

Map-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:here_sdk/core.dart';
import 'package:here_sdk/mapview.dart';

void main() {
  SdkContext.init(IsolateOrigin.main);
  runApp(SecondRoute());
}

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HereMap(onMapCreated: _onMapCreated),
    );
  }

  void _onMapCreated(HereMapController hereMapController) {
    hereMapController.mapScene.loadSceneForMapScheme(MapScheme.normalDay,
        (MapError error) {
      if (error != null) {
        print('Map scene not loaded. MapError: ${error.toString()}');
        return;
      }

      const double distanceToEarthInMeters = 8000;
      hereMapController.camera.lookAtPointWithDistance(
          GeoCoordinates(51.499293, -0.125364), distanceToEarthInMeters);
    });
  }
}
```

System.log -

[image]

When i 'run' from the map.dart page it displays and functions as an isolated page. However, when I navigate to the page from a button within my Home.dart page it crashes within 5 seconds.

This leads me to think it's an issue with the code on map.dart needing adapting after becoming SecondRoute instead of main.dart, as it is designed to be in the example.

It crashes as the map begins to load, with the following in the debug console.

```
    version=2.10.2 (stable) (Tue Oct 13 15:50:27 2020 +0200) on "ios_x64"
pid=78618, thread=771, isolate_group=(nil)(0x0), isolate=(nil)(0x0)
isolate_instructions=0, vm_instructions=103933440
  pc 0x0000000103a65974 fp 0x00007ffeec8650b0 dart::Profiler::DumpStackTrace(void*)+0x64
  pc 0x0000000103933592 fp 0x00007ffeec865190 dart::Assert::Fail(char const*, ...)+0x82
  pc 0x0000000103ab2526 fp 0x00007ffeec8651d0 dart::GetThreadForNativeCallback(unsigned long, unsigned long)+0xf6
  pc 0x0000000109b86f6e fp 0x00007ffeec8651e0 Unknown symbol
  pc 0x404a43f5d78811b2 fp 0x00007ffeec865310 Unknown symbol
  pc 0x00000001058fc256 fp 0x00007ffeec865330 here_sdk_std_string_get_value+0x74ae6
  pc 0x00000001058fc018 fp 0x00007ffeec865350 here_sdk_std_string_get_value+0x748a8
  pc 0x000000010570d7cd fp 0x00007ffeec865360 /Users/alexander/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B095BB61-8E50-4B46-BB0C-DC776EF0A0AE/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/879C5549-A6DF-42D0-B9D6-16391BAD86D4/Runner.app/Frameworks/heresdk.framework/heresdk+0x157cd
  pc 0x000000010578dd34 fp 0x00007ffeec865420 /Users/alexander/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B095BB61-8E50-4B46-BB0C-DC776EF0A0AE/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/879C5549-A6DF-42D0-B9D6-16391BAD86D4/Runner.app/Frameworks/heresdk.framework/heresdk+0x95d34
  pc 0x000000010578db89 fp 0x00007ffeec865440 /Users/alexander/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B095BB61-8E50-4B46-BB0C-DC776EF0A0AE/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/879C5549-A6DF-42D0-B9D6-16391BAD86D4/Runner.app/Frameworks/heresdk.framework/heresdk+0x95b89
  pc 0x00007fff2010532f fp 0x00007ffeec865460 _dispatch_call_block_and_release+0xc
  pc 0x00007fff20106508 fp 0x00007ffeec865480 _dispatch_client_callout+0x8
  pc 0x00007fff20112ff7 fp 0x00007ffeec865520 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF+0x415
  pc 0x00007fff2038fdbb fp 0x00007ffeec865530 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__+0x9
  pc 0x00007fff2038a63e fp 0x00007ffeec866260 __CFRunLoopRun+0xa7d
  pc 0x00007fff203896d6 fp 0x00007ffeec866300 CFRunLoopRunSpecific+0x237
  pc 0x00007fff2c257db3 fp 0x00007ffeec866320 GSEventRunModal+0x8b
  pc 0x00007fff24696cf7 fp 0x00007ffeec866390 -[UIApplication _run]+0x390
  pc 0x00007fff2469bba8 fp 0x00007ffeec8663d0 UIApplicationMain+0x65
  pc 0x000000010339b1bb fp 0x00007ffeec866410 main+0x4b
  pc 0x00007fff2025a3e9 fp 0x00007ffeec866420 start+0x1
-- End of DumpStackTrace
     Lost connection to device.
```

Comment: Post your crash\error log, debug console output.

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad Have updated post with system.log and debug console output. Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is possibly caused by this code `(MapError error) {
 if (error != null) { print('Map scene not loaded. MapError: ${error.toString()}');
 return;
  }`

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad, this code would just print something when loading fails. It should not crash.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that shows how to load a new map screen from a button:

```
class MyHome extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          HereMap(onMapCreated: (HereMapController mapController) {
            print('*** Calling loadScene()');

            mapController.mapScene.loadSceneForMapScheme(
              MapScheme.normalDay,
              (MapError loadSceneError) {
                print('*** Map scene loaded successfully');

                if (loadSceneError != null) {
                  print('*** Failed to load map scene ($loadSceneError)');
                  return;
                }
              },
            );
          }),
          PlatformButton(
            child: const Text('Navigate to a new map page'),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.push<void>(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute<void>(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => HereMap(onMapCreated: (HereMapController mapController) {
                  print('*** Calling loadScene() 2');

                  mapController.mapScene.loadSceneForMapScheme(
                    MapScheme.normalDay,
                    (MapError loadSceneError) {
                      if (loadSceneError != null) {
                        print('Failed to load map scene ($loadSceneError)');
                        return;
                      }
                      print('*** Map scene loaded successfully 2');
                    },
                  );
                }),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It's taken from https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/issues/71.